# Telerik Treelist NeedDataSource doesn't load data

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm trying to load treelist, everything works well but i always see "No Records To Display".

Here is the control:

```
<telerik:RadTreeList ID="trlProductGroups" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5"
        DataKeyNames="ID" ParentDataKeyNames="PARENT_ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        OnInsertCommand="trlProductGroups_InsertCommand" OnNeedDataSource="trlProductGroups_NeedDataSource"
        OnUpdateCommand="trlProductGroups_UpdateCommand" OnDeleteCommand="trlProductGroups_DeleteCommand">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:TreeListEditCommandColumn UniqueName="InsertCommandColumn" ButtonType="ImageButton"
                HeaderStyle-Width="60px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <telerik:TreeListEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" ButtonType="ImageButton">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="MyImageButton" />
            </telerik:TreeListEditCommandColumn>
            <telerik:TreeListButtonColumn UniqueName="DeleteCommandColumn" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"
                ButtonType="ImageButton" />
            <telerik:TreeListBoundColumn DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" HeaderText="Grup ID"
                ReadOnly="true" />
           <%-- <telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn DataField="GROUP_NAME" UniqueName="GROUP_NAME" HeaderText="Grup Adı">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGroupName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn>--%>
            <telerik:TreeListBoundColumn DataField="GROUP_NAME" UniqueName="GROUP_NAME" HeaderText="Grup Adı" />
            <telerik:TreeListBoundColumn DataField="PARENT_ID" UniqueName="PARENT_ID" HeaderText="Ana Grup ID"
                ReadOnly="true" />
        </Columns>
    </telerik:RadTreeList>
```

And here is the NeedDataSource Code:

```
 protected void trlProductGroups_NeedDataSource(object sender, TreeListNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {

            WebAppTest.Objects.ProductGroups pGroups = new WebAppTest.Objects.ProductGroups();
            DataTable dt = pGroups.SelectData(null, string.Empty);
            trlProductGroups.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

I can see the data in DataTable, but treelist wont load data. Is there any mistake i make?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is correct. It is not about RadScriptManager and RadAjaxLoadingPanel either. Could you post the screen shot of DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

It's needs to be, at least one data has null id_parent value in datasoruce. Maybe it helps.